# How to query for parent theme(s)?

Tags: theming

Drupal lets you sub-theme a theme, basically like inheritance.  How can I print out a list of all themes that a drupal site is 'using'.  For example: actual theme -> parent theme 1 -> base theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) does it:

```
// Get layouts defined in the default theme and base theme (if applicable).
$theme = variable_get('theme_default');
$themes = list_themes();

$base_theme = array();
$ancestor = $theme;
while ($ancestor && isset($themes[$ancestor]->base_theme)) {
  $ancestor = $themes[$ancestor]->base_theme;
  $base_theme[] = $themes[$ancestor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Devel and devel_themer  modules. Go to the page you want to see where the output is coming from. Check the box at lower left corner which devel_themer creates. Click on the element, it will display which template was used and what are other alternatives. It aslo tell you which theme_function was used you can copy that function in you theme's template.php file name it as yourtheme_function and customize it. (Remember to enable the devel_themer module only when you are looking for templates or theme functions. It adds lots and lots of spans to html of the site)